# Art-related idiom

Tags: phrases, expressions, idiom-requests, popular-refrains

Is there an art-related idiom that compares two things/people as being alike but different in some way? For example, if I were comparing two bankers who are different, I'd say they were two sides of the same coin.

I'm trying to find ***something related to painting/sculpting*.**

Comment: A [diptych](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diptych) (art), a double-feature (film), flip side (LP records),

Comment: I'm thinking that a diptych is a continuation of the same painting. A double feature implies sequential difference, rather than difference existing within the same thing. The LP is very close, but I'm trying to find something related to painting/sculpting.

Comment: A double feature does not imply sequel: they are (were)  2 different movies played one after the other usually on a Saturday afternoon (alas, the good old days). A diptych is often  a hinged relief. To me it seems very close  to the coin metaphor.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I'm trying to refer to two artists who existed at the same time, just as the single coin has two sides, the single LP has two sides, etc. The movies happen one after the other. That's what I meant by sequential (not sequel). Do you think diptychs commonly present two opposing viewpoints on each panel, or are they usually the continuation of a theme?

Comment: Two themes on the same subject.

Comment: ab2, I like that, considering they often had opposing ways of expressing themselves.

Comment: Not specific to art, but **cut from the same cloth** is at least in this ballpark. I guess you could play on that and say the were **hewn/carved from the same stone/rock**.

Comment: Two colors on the same pallet

Comment: @Jim, _palette_ ;)

Comment: @vanderpn - Yeah, I know.  My computer is dead. I’ve been using my phone and its dreaded word-mangling keyboard.

Comment: two sides of the same chisel

Comment: Are you talking about two different things being combined or compared?

Comment: I'm comparing two artists who were very similar in temperament but very different in style.

Comment: Since you didn't like "cut from the same stone" (sculpting) or "from the same palette" (painting), are you trying to find an idiom that somehow incorporates both painting and sculpting? I suggest dropping that idea, and just use something suggestive, like "singing from the same hymnal".

Answer (score 1):

One could say the son of a sculptor was "a chip off the old block."

Comment: This is more a comparison of one thing, usually a person, from a more established thing, or person. Almost always a way to describe a son in comparison to his father.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any common ones, but why not invent your own?

Two acts of the same play.

Two editions of the same book.

Two recordings of the same song.

Comment: I will do that if I haven't missed something that already exists.

Comment: How can a request for an idiom be answered 'Why not invent your own?'?

Answer (score 0):

I thought about **different shades of gray** - and yes - with the small 'g' :) The colour connotation is obvious. Two things looking the same on first glance, but when it comes to the details..

Comment: I'm comparing a sculptor and a painter who had very similar, yet very different, approaches to art. So using the color gray would not work, in my mind. But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

**Mock'd by the same hand**.  The reference is to Shelley's poem *Ozymandias*. The spelling is from his [original manuscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozymandias).  It's a fairly well-known poem, with allusions to the fate of sculpture that may be relevant to what you are trying to convey.

Comment: I'd use this if I were writing for adults, but my audience is the younger crowd. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: If it's a really young crowd, the clay animation work in Wallace & Gromit might give you some examples.